# How to check if CMake install script is being run by CPack?

Tags: cmake, cpack

I want to detect if my `install(SCRIPT script.cmake)` is running under CPack (`make package`) or just regular `make install`. 
I have tried using:

```
if(DEFINED CPACK_OUTPUT_CONFIG_FILE)
if(DEFINED CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE)
if(DEFINED CPACK_GENERATOR)
```

Comment: In general, you should not try different things. CPack kind of records the install script and uses it to create the package. Doing things different will be confusing.

Comment: I want to know the solution of same issue. I want to change RPATH settings accoding to runnning cpack or not.

Comment: I need a solution too. I have an install command that runs a postinst script `install( CODE "EXECUTE_PROCESS( COMMAND ${postinst} )"  )` installing the app's .desktop file & making some links. The script IS set as postinst for DEB & RPM. I need this install command so postinst will be run on `cmake --install` too. It needs sudo to make the links and run xdg-desktop-menu. When run by cpack I get permission denied errors. CPack does continue and builds the packages so perhaps I should just not worry but the errors might cause CI to break. I want to prevent CPack running this install command.